# Function to return a sheet name no longer working

Tags: excel, vba

I had a function to return the name of the 7th sheet in my workbook:

```
Function FirstBBSName()

Application.Volitile True
FirstBBSName = Worksheets(7).Name

End Function
```

Then on the sheet I would refer to it like so:

```
="'"&FirstBBSName()&"'!"
```

I can then use it in other `INDRECT` formula and what not.
I need the above as the 7th sheet may or may not be present and it's name could be different every time.

It worked, but my problem was that it returned the name of the 7th sheet of whatever workbook was open and being changed, due to `Application.Volitile` and `Worksheets(7).Name`. Which is not what I intend it to do. It should only return the name of the 7th sheet of the workbook the code is in.

I tried to alter the funtion to do this, but failed, so I returned it to the code above, exactly how it was before. Now I only receive a `#VALUE` error on my sheet when I try to get the output.

Why would this be?

(Yes the sheet is present at the moment, there are 9 sheets on the workbook currently.)

Comment: Have you tried `FirstBBSName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's `Volatile`, not `Volitile`. :)

Second, you need to specify `ThisWorkbook` as the containing workbook:

```
Function FirstBBSName()

Application.Volatile True
FirstBBSName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Name

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, that is it! Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to see